# How can I specify which properties of a flex object are encoded in XML?

Tags: apache-flex

I know the class SimpleXMLEncoder can encode all properties of an Object in XML. I only want some properties encoded. How can I specify which properties to encode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but try adding the [Transient] metadata tag to any properties you do not want encoded.

Ex:

```
[Transient]
public var doNotEncodeThis:String;
```

Comment: Please note, if you are using BlazeDS this will also prevent that property from being sent back to the server.